# Monitoring a large array of load cells

Tags: analog, instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell, wheatstone-bridge

I have a large array of 8x8 load cells I'd like to monitor, and I'm looking for an efficient way to do that.

Obviously, one option is 64 independent instrumentation amplifiers, but that's expensive and involved. Another option is 8 instrumentation amps with 8 x 1:8 differential analog switches, or a single instrumentation amp with a 1:64 differential analog switch. These options reduce the total component count and cost, but still has a significant overhead. I'm wondering if it's possible to solve this with a matrix configuration, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa7xrO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly, there are parasitic paths here: in the configuration shown, SW1 measures R1+R4 in parallel with R11+R13, while SW2 measures R12+R14 in parallel with R16+R18. However, because the bridge is matched, the effect from the selected cell is twice that of any other signal. It seems like it ought to be possible, by measuring all the cells in the matrix and doing a little differential math, to extract the value of each individual cell.

Am I right about this? Is there a better configuration? And how do I go about determining the individual readings from the matrix of output values?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about parasitics because you can probably calibrate them out doing a 'no-load' measurement.

Comment: @vrleboss The 'parasitics' vary depending on the load on the other cells, though.

Comment: the parasitics will also vary with off-axis load on the load cells, that will make them hard to compensate against.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably work just as you suggest.
As to how to determine the individual load cell numbers, you have four
switch positions, so you'll generate four equations.   There are four unknowns.   Measuring, quicker than the situation changes, with all four switch settings, you can solve. The four values measured will be related to the 'pure' input values in a linear way, so it's a matrix equation. The matrix inverse acting on the measured values, gives the load cell values. One wants to know the noise and signal sensitivity (this will come from an eigenvalue analysis).
Do the math FIRST, if the matrix isn't invertible, that's a show-stopper. 
You'll need to worry about electrical pickup of the wiring, since your amplifier
gain will be applied at some distance from the load cells.